# MIB episode- begins in a movie theater

Tags: episode-identification, men-in-black

In the teaser to this particular episode of MIB the series, K and J track an alien criminal to a crowded cinema; when J asks how they're to identify their suspect, K points out the one moviegoer rooting for the alien on the screen. As J collars their suspect, K says something like "Remember, it's only a movie" to the rest of the audience right before he zaps them with his memory eraser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *Men in Black: The Series* S01E09, "**[The Psychic Link Syndrome](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0646315/?ref_=ttmc_mc_tt)**".

From IMDB:

> A psychotic alien cab driver, is inexplicably attacking innocent humans and draining them of their vital "life force". While attempting to overtake the disturbed cabbie, Kay is attacked and imbued with the alien's "essence". Psychically bonded to the alien and capable of feeling his pain, Kay refuses an antidote reasoning that his condition will aid in capturing the rogue Alcidian. As the pursuit escalates, Kay identifies more closely with the deranged alien and eventually turns against his fellow agents. It's a life or death situation for their partner; Jay and Elle must quickly devise a plan to bring down the violent Alcidian without harming Kay.

The scene in question plays out in the first minute of the episode, just as you described: